# A simple calculus problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is an example A-Level (UK) question: the volume of a sphere $V cm^3$ is related to its radius $r$ by the formula $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$. The surface area of the sphere is also related to the radius by the formula $S = 4 \pi r^2$. Given that the rate of decrease in the surface area, in $cm^2 s^{-1}$, is $\frac{dS}{dt} = -12$, find the rate of decrease of volume $\frac{dV}{dt}$.

Here are two solutions - one from a student, the other from the given solution. They arrive at different answers. Which is correct? Why is the incorrect solution wrong?

Solution (1):
From $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$ and $S = 4 \pi r^2$, we get $$V =  \frac{r}{3} S$$
So, $$\frac{dV}{dS} = \frac {r}{3}$$

Now, $$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dS} \times \frac{dS}{dt}$$

$$ = \frac{r}{3} \times {-12}$$
$$ = {-4r}$$

Solution (2):
Now, $$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dr} \times \frac{dr}{dS} \times \frac{dS}{dt}$$
From $V=\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$ and $S = 4 \pi r^2$ we get $$\frac{dV}{dr} = 4 \pi r^2$$ and $$\frac{dS}{dr} = 8 \pi r$$
So, $$\frac{dV}{dt} = {4 \pi r^2} \times \frac{1}{8 \pi r} \times {-12}$$
$$= \frac{r}{2} \times {-12}$$
$$={-6r}$$

Which is the correct answer ${-4r}$ or ${-6r}$ ?

Comment: $r$ is not a constant so you cannot write $\frac{dV}{dS} = \frac{r}{3}$. This is because the rate of decrease of the surface area is related to its radius, which is changing.

Comment: @Toby Mak This is a complete answer to the question, may be You want to post it as such, so that its clear the question is answered.

Comment: @PeterMelech Sure thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r$ is not a constant so you cannot write $\frac{dV}{dS} = \frac{r}{3}$. This is because the rate of decrease of the surface area is related to its radius, which is changing.

In general, you should try to figure out what topic the problem is about (chain rule), and then apply a key fact about the topic, and work through the steps. This makes your 'train of thought' clearer, and can also help prevent silly mistakes, like what the second solution does.

Answer (score 0):

Like Toby Mak said, the surface area changes with time because the radius of the sphere changes with time. Thus, $S = S(t)$ and $r = r(t)$. Applying the chain rule, we get $\frac{dS}{dt} = 4 \pi \frac{d}{dt} [r^{2}(t)] = 4 \pi \times 2r(t)r'(t) = 8 \pi r(t) \frac{dr}{dt}$. Since $\frac{dS}{dt} = -12$, solving for $\frac{dr}{dt}$ gives us $\frac{dr}{dt} = -\frac{3}{2 \pi r(t)}$. Now, we apply the chain rule to the volume formula to get $\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{4}{3} \pi \times 3 r^{2}(t) \frac{dr}{dt} = 4 \pi r^{2}(t) \frac{dr}{dt}$. Substituting in the expression for $\frac{dr}{dt}$ yields $\frac{dV}{dt} = 4 \pi r^{2}(t) \times -\frac{3}{2 \pi r(t)} = -6r(t)$.